# Leaflet WMTS wrong tile order

Tags: leaflet, wmts

I added a WMTS Layer to a Leaflet map. The tiles are loading but aren't in the correct order.
Has anyone ever encountered this problem? If so, how did you overcome it?

[image]

```
    var map = new L.Map('viewerDiv', {
         crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857
    });
    var url =
        'http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/World_Topo_Map/default/default028mm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var tilelayer = new L.tileLayer(url, {
        tileSize: 256,
        tms: true,
        attribution: 'World Map'
    });
    map.addLayer(tilelayer);
    map.setView(L.latLng(50, 8), 4);
```

http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Comment: do you have your z,x,and y coordinates correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the tileset capabilites, you'll notice line `<TileMatrixSet>GoogleMapsCompatible</TileMatrixSet>`, which means this is standard Google Maps tileset. As @nmtoken pointed out, this means that `x` and `y` order should be reversed and that this is not TMS layer, so layer option `tms` should be left out:

```
var tilelayer = new L.tileLayer(
  'http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/World_Topo_Map/default/default028mm/{z}/{y}/{x}.png',
  {
    tileSize: 256,
    attribution: 'World Map'
  }
);
```